# Rewrite wordpress sanitize_user function to disallow whitespace for username registration form

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, registration

In wordpress, the sanitize_user() function allows you to define the restriction rules applied to the different forms. The one that interests me here is the registration form and I am trying to personalize this form. I used the Wordpress Theme my login plugin and everything is working fine. However during registration, I want to prevent users from entering a Username with whitespaces. By default, the sanitize_user() function allow username with whitespaces (eg: John Doe) but i don't want it, ***i just want them to write username without whitespaces.***

This is the defaut sanitize_user() function :

```
function sanitize_user( $username, $strict = false ) {
$raw_username = $username;
$username     = wp_strip_all_tags( $username );
$username     = remove_accents( $username );
// Kill octets.
$username = preg_replace( '|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '', $username );
// Kill entities.
$username = preg_replace( '/&.+?;/', '', $username );

// If strict, reduce to ASCII for max portability.
if ( $strict ) {
    $username = preg_replace( '|[^a-z0-9 _.\-@]|i', '', $username );
}

$username = trim( $username );
// Consolidate contiguous whitespace.
$username = preg_replace( '|\s+|', ' ', $username );

/**
 * Filters a sanitized username string.
 *
 * @since 2.0.1
 *
 * @param string $username     Sanitized username.
 * @param string $raw_username The username prior to sanitization.
 * @param bool   $strict       Whether to limit the sanitization to specific characters.
 */
return apply_filters( 'sanitize_user', $username, $raw_username, $strict );
```

}

I've tried to pass function to strict but no result (`function sanitize_user( $username, $strict = true ) {...}`;

Did somebody can help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_user', 'remove_whitespace_from_username', 10, 3 );
function remove_whitespace_from_username( $username, $raw_username, $strict  ){
    $username = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $username);
    return $username;
}
```

you can also use below code for remove whitespace

You can go with str_replace() also:-

```
$username = str_replce(' ','',$username);
```

Comment: Okay thank you, but it's not working as well. i found something else, and it work for me, the code : 
`function custom_validate_username($valid, $username)
{
  if (preg_match("/\\s/", $username)) {
    // there are spaces
    return $valid = false;
  }
  return $valid;
}
add_filter('validate_username', 'custom_validate_username', 10, 2);`

Comment: Ok, I don't know you wanted to validate the username. My code will remove space from the user name.